# Post Image on Facebook Page Feed as Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Using this example from fb-sdk:

```
require_once 'fb-sdk/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '123456',
  'app_secret' => 'abc1233',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.6',
  ]);

$data = [
  'message' => 'Testupload',
  'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('image.jpg'),
];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/PageID/photos', $data, 'XXXXXXYYYYYY');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];
```

i am able to post as myself to the wall of my facebook-page.
'app_id' and 'app_secret' come from the app i created for this.

If i set $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, 'XXXXXXYYYYYY'); the post shows up on my timeline.

What do i need to change, so get a photo, posted by "Page" on the feed of "Page"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Page Token with the `publish_pages` permission to post "as Page". You can get a Page Token with the following API call, after authorizing with `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`:

```
/page-id?fields=access_token
```

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ was perfect! i did not know, that the "page access token" is not the same as in the graph api explorer. now it works. just needed to subsitute this token in php-file